# Python - pascals triangle

Tags: python

Hello I am stuck with this excercise. I am doing pascal's triangle, but cant seem to get it right enough so checking programme from my college would accept it. 
I must use `def pascals_triangle(n)` where `n=8`. I can get that working, but the problem is in output - i get arrays... 
like that:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
```

Also the definition says that each row should be written in row of a **matrix P[64]** and that empty places should be put to 0. I must use for loop and print command for one row should look like this:

```
print "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d" % (P[0],P[1],P[2],P[3],P[4],P[5],P[6],P[7],P[8])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you be more specific about the meaning of input `n` and the format of the output and what code have you tried exactly to get the output from your arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at something like this:

```
def pascal_iteration(n):
    rows = list()
    lr = None
    for i in range(n+1):
        try:
            lr = [1] + [lr[i] + lr[i+1] for i in range(len(lr) - 1)] + [1]
        except Exception:
            lr = [1]
        rows.append(' '.join(str(v) for v in lr))
    return rows

rows = pascal_iteration(8)
l = len(rows[-1])
print '\n'.join(v.center(l) for v in rows)
```

Output:

```
          1           
         1 1          
        1 2 1         
       1 3 3 1        
      1 4 6 4 1       
    1 5 10 10 5 1     
   1 6 15 20 15 6 1   
 1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1  
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
```

Comment: this looks nice, but it kind of violates almost every requirement in the question...

Comment: i don't have an answer yet, i asked the OP what the output format means - but your output doesn't even look like 8x8 matrix with empty places set to 0

Comment: I though this is what OP implied.